# How can I create a new categories in an existing dataframe?

Tags: pandas, data-science

I have a data set with a column name total of payments, which include payments from $100 to $1000, there are some payments that are $100.05, $102 or 104.05, which make it more difficult. If the row says for instance $97, then I want to create a column that have the categories below $100 or between 100 and 200.

I have coded something like this;

[image: Code Screenshot]

but the output is the following, all of the rows say Between 800 and 900;

[image: Output Screenshot]

Please support on this folks.

Comment: Please [read this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5241032) about why not to post images of code, [and this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) about how to create a minimal, complete, and verifiable example.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `pandas.cut()`
Consider this dummy df

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Total_payments': [97, 110, 100.5, 370, 820, 600]})
```

You can add a bracket column using `pd.cut()`

```
labels = ['<100', '100-200','200-300','300-400','400-500','500-600','600-700','700-800','800-900']
df['Brackets'] = pd.cut(df['Total_payments'], \
bins = np.arange(0, df['Total_payments'].max()+100, 100), labels = labels)


    Total_payments  Brackets
0   97.0            <100
1   110.0           100-200
2   100.5           100-200
3   370.0           300-400
4   820.0           800-900
5   600.0           500-600
```

Edit: updated the answer with `labels` parameter as suggested by @Mikhail Venkov

Comment: You can also use 'labels' parameter to pass a list of string to be used as labels for your bins. Also bins can be a list of boundaries that are not evenly spaced.